# What is Ruby's equivalent of Python's hash()?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have an `Array`: `['a', 'b', 'c']`. I want to record whether I have seen a particular array before.

I can put the array in a `Set`, but that is wasteful if I don't need to store the contents of the array, only that I have seen it before.

In Python, I could hash a tuple (i.e. `hash(('a', 'b', 'c'))`) and store the result in a set to achieve this. What is the way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: @tadman (response to deleted comment) maybe I should have included a more detailed Python example. I am envisioning something like (Python) `hash(('a', 'b', 'c')) in {hash(('a', 'b', 'c'))}`. It sounds like `Object#hash` is what I'm looking for though - if that's what `Set` or `Hash` use for arrays as keys, then it's good enough for this.

Comment: First: Hashing isn't compression. You can't save `O(space)`. Second: Storing pointers is cheap. Just use `Set`.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek this may be reasonably accurate when the arrays contain very simple objects. But if they refer to objects with a large footprint, and so prevent them from being garbage collected, then it is not ideal.

Comment: If probabilistic accuracy is enough, then go ahead. Just don't use it anywhere where data might be lost.

Comment: Also, you can increase the probabilistic accuracy by using a [bloom filter](https://github.com/igrigorik/bloomfilter-rb). Just like comparing hash values, a bloom filter can tell you "definitely not seen" or "may have seen", with higher accuracy, and modest increase in memory consumption, over a plain hash value comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby has `#hash` on most objects, including Array, but these values are **not** unique and will eventually collide.

For any serious use I'd strongly suggest using something like SHA2-256 or stronger as these are cryptographic hashes designed to minimize collisions.

For example:

```rb
require 'digest/sha2'

array = %w[ a b c ]

array.hash
# => 3218529217224510043

Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(array.inspect)
# => "ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad"
```

Where that value is going to be *relatively* unique. SHA2-256 collisions are really infrequent due to the sheer size of that hash, 256 bits vs. the  64 bit `#hash` value. That's not 4x stronger, it's *6.2 [octodecillion](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_large_numbers) times stronger*. That number may as well be a "zillion" given how it has 57 zeroes in it.

Comment: Please see my above comment - if `Object#hash` is used in `Set` then does it follow that it is "good enough" for the purpose here? Also, another (arguably more relevant than collision resistance) advantage of using `digest` is that the results can be used between Ruby invocations.

Comment: @biqqles Hash sets and hash maps do not assume that two elements/keys are equal just because their hash codes are. They still use `==` on the elements/keys themselves to make sure that they're actually equal. So the hash function doesn't need to be that strong because a hash collision isn't the end of the world. If you don't keep the values around and only rely on the hash code, that's a whole different ball game because you'll get wrong results when there's a hash collision.

Comment: @sepp2k thanks, that makes a lot of sense. This is technically out of scope for the question but do you know how `Set` handles the case where upon insertion (for example) `eql?` shows the objects are not the same but the hashes collide?

Comment: @biqqles I don't know specifically how `Hash` and `Set` do it in Ruby (and that may differ from implementation to implementation and version to version anyway), but the commonly used approaches to collision handling are explained on [the wiki page about hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) for example.

Comment: @biqqles According to [the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/st.c) they use open addressing in current versions of MRI at least.

Comment: @sepp2k: Nitpick: `Hash`, `Set`, `uniq`, `uniq!` and other "hashtable-like" or "set-like" applications use `eql?`, not `==`. In fact, that is more or less the only use of `eql?` in Ruby.

Comment: `Hash` and `Set` use `#hash` as a quick test, then `eql?` as a secondary test. For instance, if your `#hash` value isn't found then you know for sure it's not in the `Set`, however if it is found you must test any matching values to see if there's an exact match or not. With a good `#hash` value you can only minimize unnecessary tests, not eliminate the possibility of them.

Comment: Note that Python's `hash` function is about the same "strength" as Ruby's `#hash` method, and neither language uses the hash as the sole factor for determining presence in hashed structures. If you are using Python's `hash` to ascertain identity, it will fail just like in Ruby. The only difference really is the fact that Ruby allows hashing of mutable objects (trusting the developer to be smart about it), and Python does not.

Comment: _"that value is going to be relatively unique"_ – you have to choose the value you are hashing carefully. In the shown example, `%w[a b c]`, `%w[ab c]`, `%w[a bc]` and `%w[abc]` would all have the same SHA2 hash due to the way `join('')` works. Better use `to_s` / `to_json` / `Marshal.dump`.

Comment: @Stefan There's many ways to crack this nut, and yeah, those are improvements on the same basic idea. I've changed the example to `.inspect` as for plain data that's probably the quickest. For anything with objects that have `#NNN` type stuff in them, worth doing `to_json` or `Marshal.dump` as you suggest. All about trade-offs.